# Does all touchscreen supported to linux work on raspberry pi?

Tags: linux, touchscreen

I am working on a project for a large smart mirror, around 42 inches. To this i will also use a touchscreen for interaction with the screen and the supplier for the touch foil assures that the system is compatible to Linux. Can i assume that i can use the touchscreen on the raspberry pi 3b with any Linux-based system?

Comment: Do you have more information as to what make/model/specs the screen is incase someone has worked with it before and can confirm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assume anything you want.

I would not assume that since a device works on one Linux system it will work on all others.

- Perhaps the device needs more processing power or RAM than the Pi can supply.
- Perhaps the device uses an interface that the Pi does not support.
- Perhaps the device relies on closed source drivers which are only available for incompatible CPU architectures.

**You will have to test the device yourself**.

Comment: ✋Hilarious, but this guy is talking about standards!